# Error 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, textview

I had this errors

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

in this - holder.Plan.setText(model.getTypeOfPlan());

and this -public class padapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter {

how can I resolve it, hope you guys help for that

and this the code

```
    public class padapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<addp, padapter.profileHolder> {


    private  OnItemClickListener listener;
    public padapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<addp> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull profileHolder holder, int position, @NonNull addp model) {
        holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());
        holder.Plan.setText(model.getTypeOfPlan());
        holder.Price.setText(model.getPrice());
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public profileHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.profile_item, parent, false);
        View Plan = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, parent, false);
        View Price = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, parent, false);


        return new profileHolder(v);

    }

    class profileHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewName;
        TextView Plan;
        TextView Price;




        public profileHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Text_view_name);
            Plan = itemView.findViewById(R.id.View_Plan_cart);
            Price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.View_Plan_price);


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),position);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

 public interface  OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a generalised answer, since this is something you will face multiple times while developing Android/Java code. (java.lang.NullPointerException).

This is how you solve it;

1. Ensure you check all Nullable items for correct initialization.
   For instance in your case, instead of second guessing which object is null include if statements that check for Nulls, like so,

   ```
   if(holder != null ){

      if(model != null){
         holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());
         holder.Plan.setText(model.getTypeOfPlan());
         holder.Price.setText(model.getPrice());
      }else
         Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),"model object is Null...");
   }else 
     Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "holder object is null...");
   ```

You can use this during debugging, once you establish the object causing the NullPointerException you can proceed to properly initialize it and then you can get rid of the if-statements or checks.

Hope this helps, now and in the future... :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `model.getTypeOfPlan()` is returning `null`, in that case you need to provide more codes to show where it is from.